# Rails3 responding with js after json update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

using http://blog.bernatfarrero.com/in-place-editing-with-javascript-jquery-and-rails-3/

The gem uses json to update, but how can I trigger my update.js.erb to update the different parts of my pages?

EDIT
Using this in an invoice page.  every item in the invoice has a price field that can be updated with best_in_place.

I need to update the Total Price for line item and amount due for invoice only after field has been updated successfully.

Ended up with something like:

```
 respond_to do |format|
        if @item.update_attributes(params[:item])
          format.html { redirect_to order_url(@item.order_id), :notice => "Successfully updated item." }
          format.js {  }
          format.json { head :ok }
```

Edited best_in_place.js line #175

```
loadSuccessCallback : function(data) {
    this.element.html(data[this.objectName]);
        // Binding back after being clicked
    $(this.activator).bind('click', {editor: this}, this.clickHandler);
    if(this.objectName == "item") $.getScript('update.js'); // If its an item, call update.js.erb 
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a view update.js.erb. As ezkl already pointed out, you need to set the respond_to of your controller to json. In addition, you need to activate best-in-place in your public/javascripts/application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place()
});
```

and add it in your view:

```
 <td><%= best_in_place task, :name, :type => :input, :nil => "Click to edit" %></td>
```

I have a tutorial on Ajax with Prototype and JQuery on my own site - and the JQuery Part uses best-in-place: http://www.communityguides.eu/articles/15

Comment: Can I have jquery do a getscript(); if best_in_place is successful?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Best_in_place takes user input, sends that to the controller and the controller returns json to best_in_place. You can't have two responses like .js and .json at once. However, in the controller you can do whatever you want as long as you return the json.

Comment: best_in_place is working correctly, what I would like to do is update the other fields on the invoice page once best_in_place has done its job.  User comes to invoice page > user edits item > best_in_place does its thing > on best_in_place success something (controller or another js) calls my update.js.  also updated question

Comment: I don't see an option to do that in the source of http://github.com/bernat/best_in_place/blob/master/public/javascripts/best_in_place.js.

Comment: was hoping it could be done from controller.  easier for me, but edited the best_in_place.js.  Question has sample of what I did.  Works, but sure there is a cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: It kept me thinking about, I just tried to do something weird: format.json { render 'update.js.erb' }  Best_in_place keeps working, server log states "Rendered tasks/update.js.erb (0.6ms)", however, the alert('hi') in there is not displayed.

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to do the exact same thing with best_in_place pcasa.  In the current version (1.0.2), the loadSuccessCallback function triggers an ajax:success event.  That allows you to do this in your application.js:

```
$('.best_in_place')
    .best_in_place()
    .bind('ajax:success', function(e) {
        // do your post-json call magic
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something along the lines of:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      format.html { redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'User was successfully updated.') }
      format.json { head :ok }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      format.json  { render :json => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I haven't tested this with the code in the tutorial, but the idea is that you have to tell the controller method to load the Javascript file. I'm not sure how this will interact with the redirect, but the principle is correct.

Comment: Tried adding the format.js, but nothing happened with my update.js.erb